# Is there any other way to position absolute elements?

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.links-tags {
  display: flex;
}

.special,
.in-transit {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.in-transit {
  left: 67px; /*Added temporarily*/ 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
  <div class="links-tags">
    <div class="special">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="in-transit">in-transit</div>
    <div class="icon">
      <span>X</span>
      <span>Y</span>
      <span>Z</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Need to position "in-transit" tag exactly after the first tab which has dynamic text inside it. For now I have added `left: 67px` to `in-transit`

Tried `left: auto` it dose not work. Is there any other way to achieve it without changing HTML?

NOTE: I can not change the HTML.

Comment: why do you want `in-transit` to be *absolutely* positioned? just remove `absolute` position and it will come right after the dynamic content...

Comment: Want to postion the those tag exactly above the image. Is there any other position which could work here?

Comment: Do you know how high the image is exactly? Then you can position `links-tags` and `icon` absolutely instead of `special` and `in-transit`.

Comment: Image could be of any size no fixed dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap **special** & **in-transit** div in another div tag and absolute this div on top of your image. Like below:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
  <div class="links-tags">
    <div class="tags-wrap">
      <div class="special">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div class="in-transit">in-transit</div>
    </div>
    <div class="icon">
      <span>X</span>
      <span>Y</span>
      <span>Z</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.links-tags {
  display: flex;
}
.tags-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.special,
.in-transit {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Can not change HTML

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving `absolute` position for `special` and `in-transit`, give it to its wrapper div `links-tags` - see demo below:

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.links-tags {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute; /* ADDED */
  top: 0; /* ADDED */
}

.special,
.in-transit {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  top: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
  <div class="links-tags">
    <div class="special">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="in-transit">in-transit</div>
    <div class="icon">
      <span>X</span>
      <span>Y</span>
      <span>Z</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: This is usually not possible - but here is a *hack* if we assume that both `special` and `in-transit` have a width less than 50% of the image that fills up `wrap`:

1. Making `link-tags` a wrapping *flexbox* with *flex-line alignment* set to `space-between`.
2. Add `width: 50%` to `icon` and translate it down 100% of its dimension

See demo below:

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.links-tags {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute; /* ADDED */
  top: 0; /* ADDED */
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* ADDED */
  height: 100%; /* ADDED */
  align-content: space-between; /* ADDED */
}

.special,
.in-transit {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  top: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.icon { /* ADDED */
  width: 50%;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
  <div class="links-tags">
    <div class="special">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="in-transit">in-transit</div>
    <div class="icon">
      <span>X</span>
      <span>Y</span>
      <span>Z</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: XYZ needs to be below image.

Comment: @dipikapatil that is usually difficult without changing the markup, but check out the *hack* above...

Comment: This didn't really solve my problem. I had to add HTML wrapper for the two buttons.

Comment: nice to know its fixed, thanks for the follow-up, you can add an answer with your original solution :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide icons you can simply do it with `text-indent`

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.links-tags {
  display: flex;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

.special,
.in-transit {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  position:relative;
  margin:2px;
}
.icon {
  text-indent:-100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
  <div class="links-tags">
    <div class="special">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    <div class="in-transit">in-transit</div>
    <div class="icon">
      <span>X</span>
      <span>Y</span>
      <span>Z</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```